# Running unittests in Python code with C # & extract errors

Tags: c#, python, pycharm

I have a unit I implemented in Python using PyCharm, I also made a unittests for it.

I want to run the tests scripts from a c# test unit and, in case on a failure, to get the error input in the C# testing log.

Is there even a way to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: The Python Tools for Visual Studio have [unit test support](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Unit-Tests)

Comment: But how do I get a Python Unit Test to run under a C# solution?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "C# solution". A solution can contain projects of many types.